# Intel compiler and "cannot have an in-class initializer" when using constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, icc

The following test program compiles and runs fine with g++.  With Intel icpc (14.0.2) it will compile and run if I use an explicit type like double instead of the template.  The template version with icpc produces an error:

```
icpc -g -O2 -I. -std=c++0x -c main.cc -o main.o

main.cc(10): error: a member of type "const T [9]" cannot have an in-class initializer
    static constexpr T dx_[9] = {
```

**Test Code**

```
template<typename T>
class myclass {

public:

    static constexpr T dx_[9] = {
         1.5,  2.0, -0.5,
        -0.5,  0.0,  0.5,
         0.5, -2.0, -1.5
        };
};

template<typename T> constexpr T myclass<T>::dx_[9];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
} // main
```

Why am I receiving the error *"cannot have an in-class initializer"* when using a `constexpr`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug of Intel compiler, it is submitted to Intel and will be fixed in future versions.

Also see [Multiple constexpr bugs](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/540106), [sfinae bug with intel c++ compiler 15](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/536871) and [method constexpr bug with c++ compiler 15](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/536832) on the Intel forums.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your compiler is outdated. The `-std=c++0x` flag shows that it was implemented long before the C++11 standard was implemented.

Try using the `-std=c++11` switch, if you compiler supports it.

Otherwise, upgrade your compiler or don't use these fancy new features.

Comment: *don't use these fancy new features* These features are not new, but (at the time of the OP) >2 years old.

Comment: @Walter: I.e., ``constexpr`` is still not supported in full on the latest VisualStudio 2015 CTP. As much as it pains me to say it, if you are serious in compatibility, you should not use those features.

Comment: I think the flaw here is with Intel and not with the C++ users. Intel fails their customers and they should cease to pay for such poor service!

Comment: @Walter In an ideal world, i would absolutely agree. But on Windows we just use the tools we have.